# Display image from API in JS/Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, postman

I am trying to display an image that is returned via API but without success.

In the Postman it is displayed normally:

[image: postman]

But when I do the console.log of the returned data the following is displayed:

[image: console]

How do I convert this to a valid string for the `src`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that in your fetch you are trying to parse json, while you should parse as blob.

```
fetch(url, options)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(res => //do your thing here)
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: One of the questions was the type of return itself, but since I am using Axios, it was necessary to do some complementary actions according to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it was the same but for axios. You didn't say you were using it, my answer was indeed correct. You answered it yourself but not for the question you made, since you never mentioned axios.

Comment: Done! All credit to you. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Since I am using Axios, it was necessary to change the `responseType` to `"blob"`:

```
try {
    const response = await api.post(
      url,
      {
        params
      },
      {
        responseType: "blob"
      }
    );

    return URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([response.data], { type: "image/png" })
    );
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

So all you had to do was include the return in the `src` attribute of the image.